# Convert Julian date to calendar dates within a data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
> df
Age   year  sex
12    80210  F
13     9123  M
```

I want to convert the year 80210 as 26june1982. How can I do this that the new data frame contains year in day month year formate from Julian days.

Answer (score 16):

You can convert Julian dates to dates using `as.Date` and specifying the appropriate origin:

```
as.Date(8210, origin=as.Date("1960-01-01"))
#[1] "1982-06-24"
```

However, 80210 needs an origin pretty long ago.

Answer (score 3):

You should substract the origin from the year column.

```
 as.Date(c(80210,9123)-80210,origin='1982-06-26')
[1] "1982-06-26" "1787-11-08"
```

Comment: `transform` might be useful: `transform(df, Date=as.Date(year-80210,origin='1982-06-26'))`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options for doing this job in the R package [date](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/date/date.pdf).

See for example on page 4, the function `date.mmddyy`, which says:

> Given a vector of Julian dates, this returns them in the form “10/11/89”, “28/7/54”, etc.

Try this code:

```
age = c(12,13)
year = c(8210,9123)
sex = c("F","M")

df = data.frame(cbind(age,year,sex))

library(date)
date = date.mmddyy(year, sep = "/")

df2 = transform(df,year=date) #hint provided by jilber
df2

  age     year sex
1  12  6/24/82   F
2  13 12/23/84   M
```