# How to convert julian date into standard date for different years?

Tags: r, date, for-loop, dplyr, julian-date

I have julian dates for several years, I want to convert them to a standard date format (year-month-day). I tried with the following code

```
library(epitools)
library(dplyr)

df$new_date <- df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate(new_date = julian2date(julian_date))
```

but it get the following message:

```
Error: do not know how to convert 'attributes(x)[[1]]' to class “Date”
```

Comment: `mutate` will return an entire data.frame with the new variables, so you shouldn't be assigning to a column. And `as.Date` can handle Julian dates, e.g. `as.Date(paste(170:190, 2017), '%j %Y')`

Comment: get rid of the assignment. It will be added as a column to your data frame by `mutate`

Comment: [convert Julian date to calendar date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789612/convert-julian-date-to-calendar-dates-within-a-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

The julian2date() function is not needed. The following code will convert the julian_date variable to a standard date format.

```
as.Date(julian_date, origin="1970-01-01")
```