# Convert Julian Date to PosixCt Date

Tags: r, date

I find myself struggling with this problem: I need to convert a julian date to normal date ("YYYY-MM-DD") in R. I'm aware that I can specify `as.Date(julian_date,origin="")`, but I don't know which origin should be provided.

My julian dates are something like 2458010,2458011 etc..
If I stay with default origin ("1970-01-01") my dates becomes something like "8699-11-10" which is obviously wrong since I know dates should be in years 2017-2018

How do I know the correct origin for the `as.Date` function? http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm This site seems to convert my julian dates in the right way...

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789612/convert-julian-date-to-calendar-dates-within-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Nope.. As I said it returns me 8699 as year which is not correct.

Comment: Ok, I answer myself... maybe the origin date is -4713-01-01 G, the first cycle of julian date. https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Julian-date.. Now the problem is how to pass that number to the as.Date function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julian day number 0 is assigned to the day starting at noon on November 24, 4714 BC ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)).

**Wikipedia example:**

```
as.Date(2451545, origin = structure(-2440588, class = "Date"))
[1] "2000-01-01"
```

**Your example:**

```
as.Date(c(2458010,2458011), origin = structure(-2440588, class = "Date"))
[1] "2017-09-13" "2017-09-14"
```